# Injecting different implementation of one interface inside an injected class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

So lets say I have two implementation of an interface named `Vehicle`, `Bike` and `Car`. And I have a another class, named `TireStore`. And I have two other classes, lets name them `PersonA` and `PersonB`. What I want to do is whenever I am using `TireStore` in `PersonA`, I would like `Car` is injected. And whenever I use `PersonB` I would like `Bike` is injected as a `Vehicle` to `TireStore`. I don't know if it is possible...

So far I have tried annotating `PersonA` with`@Qualifier("exampleQualifier")` and also `Car` with the same. Then I annotated `Bike` as `@Primary`.

Didn't work. Searched a little bit, didn't find any solution.

Thank you in advance.

And the structure of them like this:

```
@Component
public class PersonA{

    private TireStore TireStore;

    public TireStore(TireStore tireStore){
        this.tireStore = tireStore;
    }
    ...
}
```

```
@Component
public class PersonB{

    private TireStore tireStore;

    public TireStore(TireStore tireStore){
        this.tireStore = tireStore;
    }
    ...
}
```

```
@Component
public class TireStore{

    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public TireStore(Vehicle vehicle){
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }
    ...
}
```

```
@Component
public class Bike extends Vehicle{
...
}
```

```
@Component
public class Car extends Vehicle{
...
}
```

Comment: Read in more detail how qualifiers work. You're almost there with the solution.

Comment: Also, doesn't quite sound like your design is valid. Why does person own `TireStore`? Why does `TireStore` own a `Vehicle`? Why does a person only know about the `TireStore` and not the `Vehicle`? Or is this just an arbitrary example for [mcve]?

Comment: It is just an example of the things that first came to my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the first think when dealing with this kind of problem is to rethink your architecture of the application. Because using ***@Qualifier*** annotation will solve the initial problem with wiring the same Interface in multiple Beans. But than, based on your example it is hard to wire this class to your *PersonA* or *PersonB* class without tightly coupled code.
I will show you my example how I would do it:

**Interface**:

```
public interface Vehicle(){
  //some methods you are using in this interface

}
```

**Bike class:**

```
@Component
public class Bike implements Vehicle{
  //here are the implemented methods from Vehicle Interface
}
```

**Car class:**

```
@Component
public class Car implements Vehicle{
  //here are the implemented methods from Vehicle Interface
}
```

**Tire Store class:**

```
@Component
public class TireStore{

    private Vehicle vehicle;

    public TireStore(@Qualifier("bike") Vehicle vehicle){
      this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }
}
```

The String inside the brackets of **@Qualifier** annotation is the name of the Bean. Basically you are specifically telling Spring which Bean (who is using the Vehicle interface) you want to autowire.
This is how you can use the **@Qualfier** annotation to solve at least partially the problem.

But the answer on how to fully solve your problem is to create separate Interface for each service. This is how you can avoid using **fat interfaces** which is considered as ***bad practice***

I would do it like this:
For **Bike** class I would create a ***BikeService*** Interface and rename the Bike class to ***BikeServiceImpl***.
The same will be applied for Car class.

Than I would implement both services in your ***TireStore*** class

```
@Component
public class TireStore{

  private final BikeService bikeServices;
  private final CarService carServices;

  public TireStore(BikeService bikeService, CarService carService){
    this.bikeService = bikeService;
    this.carService = carService;
  }

  // here are your methods 

}
```

Now if you want to wire this *TireStore* class into you *PersonA* and *PersonB* beans you can do it like this:

```
@Component
public class PersonA{

  private TireStore TireStore;

  public TireStore(TireStore tireStore){
    this.tireStore = tireStore;
  }

  ...
}
```

This way you will inject you TireStore bean into *PersonA* or *PersonB*. bean The best way how to do it would be to create a interface for TireStore bean and than in *PersonA* bean autowire TireStore bean by its Interface like here:

```
public interface TireStoreService(){
  //some methods or empty
}
```

and edit your ***TireStore*** bean like this

```
@Component
public class TireStore implements TireStoreService{

  private final BikeService bikeServices;
  private final CarService carServices;

  public TireStore(BikeService bikeService, CarService carService){
    this.bikeService = bikeService;
    this.carService = carService;
  }

  // here are your methods 

}
```

Now you can autowire this TireService bean into your *PersonA* and *PersonB* class like this:
For ***PersonA*** bean:

```
@Component
public class PersonA{

  private TireStoreService tireStoreService;

  public TireStore(TireStoreService tireStoreService){
    this.tireStoreService = tireStoreService;
  }

  ...
}
```

The same goes for ***PersonB*** bean

P.S. Avoid using ***empty interfaces***. If you want to wire your services/beans using meaningful interfaces you can do it and it is a good practice to do so. But if you don't have any interface to use than I suggest to do a classic ***constructor based dependency injection***

Hope this will help you. But If my response was too chaotic or bad leave a comment and I will refractor my answer

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Though, I missed the point in your answer how this will help that PersonA is using always the service injected with Car and PersonB always using Bike.

Comment: Answer for this problem is to change the layout / architecture of your application. In standard ways there isn't an easy solution for this.
Maybe you can use an if() statement to inject TireStore bean with specific Car or Bike bean  when you are using PersonA class or PersonB class but this is not a good solution.